# How to allow @throws for val(s) in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have legacy Scala code to upgrade from `2.13.3` version to `2.13.8` version. During the upgrade, I am facing the following error:

```
On line 2: error: `@throws` only allowed for methods and constructors
```

The error is occurring due to `@throws` not allowed for `val`. The code is as follows:

```
scala> @throws(classOf[Exception])
     | val a: Int = 1
       val a: Int = 1
           ^
On line 2: error: `@throws` only allowed for methods and constructors
```

Hence, how can I allow `@throws` for `val` in Scala 2.13.8.

Comment: What does it even mean? How do you throw from a val???

Comment: Just remove `@throws`